# Fast Fourier Transform MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform

I dont understand one thing when I use the function fft(x,N) in matlab, where x is the signal which I want to calculate the fourier transform and N is the number of samples. What I dont understant when I represent the fft in a graph is the amplitude. Suppose that x is a cosine wave and N=1024, why the amplitude of the two deltas are different from PI? In concrete, why N affect the amplitude in fft? What have to do with that? I hope you can understand me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read the Matlab docs (`doc fft`)? They give exactly the formula used for the DFT; from that you can directly infer the amplitude!

Comment: I read it, that's why I am asking this. The doc says that n is the length, and says that If X is a vector and the length of X is less than n, then X is padded with trailing zeros to length n. Also, it says that :If X is a vector and the length of X is greater than n, then X is truncated to length n. But I dont get it with that information, they are referring to the length, not amplitude

Comment: I was refering to the formulas in https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-5 ; your problem has nothing to do with zeropadding. Simply insert your cosine into that $Y(k)$ and test what the result is – it's never $\pi$ (I must admit I'm not even sure where your idea comes from it should be $\pi$ – you might be confusing this with the continuous Fourier transform, maybe?)

Comment: so,in $Y(k)$ the amplitude is multiplied by $W$ ?

Comment: yes, the pi comes from the fourier transform in continous time

Comment: Victor, I've closed this as a duplicate of the indicated question. If you feel this is incorrect, please edit your question and rephrase with more details about what you need to understand.